# framebuffer not available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver, framebuffer

I am trying to run an application that uses framebuffer on 2.6.31-14-generic #48-Ubuntu.

All need to do is to install a framebuffer device to get rid of the following error.

```
/dev/fb/0: No such file or directory
framebuffer not available.
FATAL: no framebuffer available
```

I googled through and found some resources indicating to do that on Grub2 I got nothing though I followed them seamlessly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question for Superuser.com.

Comment: Are there any files in /dev that start with "fb"?

Answer (score 0):

some GPU's does not have a frame buffer driver.
Such an example is the Tegra2.
A kernel upgrade might be a solution.